# Freestyle line sorting not working?

Tags: freestyle

What am I doing wrong? I can not get the sorting lines work. For the second set of lines, the settings are identical, except for the other line color.
[image: my result + settings]

Comment: Please explain in detail what your intended result is vs what is happening.

Comment: I found a mistake. I used two sets of lines, and for sorting work one is needed. If there are more than one set, then the first is superimposed on the second, and so on.

Thank you for not having missed my question. Your lessons on YouTube are excellent :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used two sets of lines in the example above, and for sorting work only one is needed. If there are more than one set, then the first is superimposed on the second, and so on.

So I changed colors with a modifier (I previously created two groups of objects and each created its own set of lines) and the sorting, finally, started to work as expected :)
[image: Sorting working!!!]